# Checking for image dimension before performing a resize in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, minimagick

I want to do an initial check for an image's dimensions.
If it is greater than 1000, then I want to apply a resize. Is this the right way to approach the problem? I'm creating an image twice. 1st time via MiniMagic to grab the dimensions and then through ImageProcessing to perform the actual resize. (I'm wondering if there's a way to do this all via 1 library)

```
@blob.open do |file|

image_to_convert = MiniMagick::Image.open(file.path)
  if(image_to_convert.width > MAX_WIDTH) 
     processed = ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(file.path).convert("png").resize_to_limit!(1000, 1000)
```

Comment: When I create an Image with Shrine I get dimensions automatically added to the record, so I can decide later if I want to create derivative images or not. Don't use MiniMagick, it is slow. Maybe use Fastimage which is the gem Shrine uses to know the image mime type and dimensions.

Comment: `resize_to_limit` just do this. "Will only resize the image if it's larger than the specified dimensions." https://github.com/janko/image_processing/blob/master/doc/minimagick.md#resize_to_limit